# Phase-shift between $\sum_{k=0}^n \cos\pi(x)$ and $\sum_{k=0}^n \cos\pi(x-k)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, trigonometry, summation

Is there an algebraic way of representing the phase-shift between the following two summations?

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \cos\pi( x)$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \cos\pi(x-k)$$

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: The summand of the first summation is a constant with respect to the dummy index $k$.

Comment: I'm probably being stupid, but I don't get this. Surely the second formula $\sum_{k=0}^n cos\pi(x-k)$ expands to $cos\pi(x-0)+cos\pi(x-1)+...+cos\pi(x-n)$. Is the phase-shift therefore given by [0+1+2+...+n]?

Comment: I am aware that $cos\pi(x)$ has period 2, and that all instances of $\sum_{k=0}^n cos\pi(x-k)=cos\pi(x)$ are... well, equivalent. But what I'm after is a systematic, algebraic solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \cos(\pi x)=(n+1)\cos(\pi x)$$

while

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \cos(\pi (x-k))=\begin{cases}
\cos(\pi x)&,n\,\text{even}\\\\0&,n\,\text{odd}\end{cases}$$

since $\cos(\pi(x-k))=(-1)^k\cos(\pi x)$.

Comment: I'l work on this then mark as proved tomorrow, if it does everything I need. Much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.